# Does "landing" strictly mean the area of the top of a staircase?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Ron was lying sprawled on his back with his mouth wide open, fast asleep. He did not stir as Harry crossed the room, stepped out onto the **landing**, and closed the door softly behind him. Trying not to think of the next time he would see Ron, when they might no longer be fellow students at Hogwarts, Harry walked quietly down the stairs, past the heads of Kreacher’s ancestors, and into the kitchen.

Does it also mean the area directly behind or in front of a door? Because the above paragraph states that Harry was still able to close the door even if he was on the landing. So it must mean something else of the landing is pretty close to his bedroom?

Comment: In Collins, [landing](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/landing) sense 3.

Comment: @user3169 So he actually reached out from landing to close his bedroom door? Is this even possible? I am Asian though so I don't know about much of western house design.

Comment: Harry is in his bedroom and the landing is the part of the house, on the other side of door, into which he steps as he walks out of his room. The landing is the sort of corridor between the rooms and the stairs. Pictures will help: [a plan](http://chestofbooks.com/food/household/Woman-Encyclopaedia-1/images/A-well-planned-First-rloor-roomy-landing-no-long-passages.jpg) and a [photo](http://www.tes-property.co.uk/photos/820x640-bound/properties/003133/HillHouseLanding1.jpg).

Comment: @Laure so actually the whole floor area, apart from bedroom area, can be referred to landing, when we are talking about when it is above ground floor? Will it be acceptable to call the landing "hall"?

Comment: I would not call a landing a hall. The hall is more the entrance area on the ground floor. But that might be subject to debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The landing is simply the part of the floor next to the top or bottom of a flight of stairs.  Landings are usually separated from rooms by doors and walls.  In homes, where landings do not need to be very wide because people are few, doors to bedrooms are often within arm's reach of a landing.

Where a landing ends and (the rest of) a hallway begins is not that precise.  Landings do not have to be a part of true hallways (or 'corridors') but can be surrounded on two or three sides by doors or walls.

Comment: Is the floor beside the leftmost door on the [picture](http://www.tes-property.co.uk/photos/820x640-bound/properties/003133/HillHouseLanding1.jpg) considered as landing(It in my sense is quite far away from the stars)?

Comment: I would say no if it's more than about 4 or 5 normal steps away.  Remember it's called a landing because that's where you 'land' when you finish climbing/going down the stairs.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK (where Harry Potter is based), the landing is typically known as the area at the top of the staircase that you access the bedrooms from.

Landing sizes vary from house to house, depending on how many rooms are upstairs.

The Hallway (or "hall" as it is more commonly known in houses) is the area between the front door and any connecting rooms. Not all British homes have a hall, some have front doors that open directly into a room.

This shouldn't be confused with the School hall, which is a large room (not unlike a gymnasium, although without the equipment) where teachers can gather most, if not all, students at once.

To summarise:

Dormitory landing - the area at the top of the stairs that provides access to the bedrooms, regardless of size.

Hall (home) - the area between the front door of a house and the internal rooms.

Hallway (home) - see above

Hallway (School) - the corridors between classrooms

Hall (School) - large meeting place

Source: I am a native English speaker from the UK.